# How to replace DrawClosedCurve / FillClosedCurve when moving from WinForms (GDI+) to WPF?

Tags: c, wpf, gdi+, bezier, curve

I've got an array of points (X,Y) which constitute a convex hull (a simple, irregularly shaped contour). Rather than rendering a polygon with straight edges, I want to render them with an approximate "smoothly curved" contour that passes through all of these points.

In WinForms/GDI+, this could be accomplished with the `Graphics.DrawClosedCurve` or `Graphics.FillClosedCurve` methods. There does not appear to be an equivalent in WPF.

I've looked into drawing using things like `Path` and `BezierSegment`, but I'm not sure if (and how) these can be used to generate a continuous closed curve, given a set of points. It appears that to do this, I'd perhaps have to generate a set of control points based on my contour as an intermediate step?

I have tried using the GDI+ methods to render onto a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and then displaying that in the WPF application. This works, but the performance (particularly the conversion from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `BitmapSource`) is poor and not sufficient for the application. This is why I'm looking for a pure WPF solution.

Has anyone been able to draw a closed curve based off a set of points in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no single-method equivalent to `DrawClosedCurve` in WPF, even though [it's been requested](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3325091-wpf-cardinal-spline-geometry). So you are left with at least two options:

- Host a native window within your WPF window and perform all your drawing on it.
- Implement your own [cardinal spline drawing](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-2D-Points-wit). You are on the right track with Bezier segments. However, there are [existing implementations of it](https://floris.briolas.nl/floris/2009/04/addcurve-for-wpf-cardinal-spline/) you can look at out there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was exactly the information I needed. Particularly the last link.